# Selenium and Python, get text without any tags from HTML body

Tags: python, selenium

need to get sentence between tags with Selenium and Python :

```
       <h2 id='PO-PF2' class="section">Program Information</h2>
        Length: Two-year Ontario College Graduate Certificate program
        <br />Delivery Sequence:<br />
```

Using  `find_element_by_xpath` in different variations didn't return any results.

Using `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text` and then parse it for required sentence works but is there any other way ?

Expected result : Length: Two-year Ontario College Graduate Certificate program

**UPD:**

```
'(?<=Length:)([\s\S]*?)(?=\n)'
```

Covered all needed cases

Comment: Could you please specify what result you are expecting?

Comment: @KshetraMohanPrusty, Thank you, after your question I got the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/SAwviM/2/): `(?=Length)(.*)(?<=program)`

`(?=...)`
Asserts that the given subpattern can be matched here, without consuming characters

`(?<=...)`
Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume any character

Comment: Yes, just solved the same way like minute ago.
Will mark as correct.

Comment: You should clarify that these are positive look-aheads and positive look-behinds